# Is there any way to create own breakpoint in my style.css in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The title says it all, I want to create a custom break point but I don't want to disturb the minified file of bootstrap. My style.css comes after minified file obviously.

EDIT: By breakpoint I mean media query breakpoint.

Comment: I wonder who down voted this. Must have no knowledge of css. It is a great question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is slightly confusing, by "breakpoint" I'm assuming you mean media query breakpoints, if you do, have a look at [this tutorial](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints) for information on that.

If by some chance you mean a breakpoint as in a breakpoint in your code like in other languages then you can't do breakpoints in CSS.

Comment: Did not help unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply write your own css with the desired media query in a new css file like `style.css` and include it "AFTER" the bootstrap.min.css in your `<head>` of HTML as you have specified. It will work fine and will override any properties in a similiar breakpoint in bootstrap.min.css

Comment: It doesn't work like this. I want to make a custom breakpoint at 535px and will be called col-xxs-x

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 535px) {
    /*your classes like col-xxs-x and their relevant properties for everything else*/
}`

Comment: it does..:) try writing some code instead of speculating.. As I have mentioned in the comment,you need to write all thee css that you want to change explicitly in your css.. for example if you want your button to become red with the specified breakpoint for class ="btn btn-default col-xxs-x" then write this: `@media screen and (min-width: 535px) { .btn btn-default col-xxs-x{ background-color: red;} }`

Comment: I have tried this already my friend. You should google it. This isn't work for breakpoints :) trust me. I know it doesn't make sense. But I was also shocked when it didnt work like that for hours. :)

Comment: Actually there isnt any overriding involved. You will understand this once you code it. When I try to override it, it overrides every other breakpoints too, because breakpoints do not have any media query. You should try this. :)

Comment: With what you are suggesting since bootstrap uses these classes:
`xs (extra small) -Phones - [0, 768px)
sm (small) -Tablets - [768px, 992px]
md (medium) -Desktops- [993px, 1200px]
lg (large) -Desktops- [1201px, infinite)` now if you need to add one more or change any of these then I guess you will have to add your own custom one into the main css or less file of bootstrap and also update the layout and grid system variables. Best of luck for that.

Comment: Yes. I want an extra class of xxs that spans [0,535px]

Comment: Have you tried modifying the less variables in the customize option? Maybe it will help solve your problem in a different approach:http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics

More specifically:http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

Comment: I don't want to disturb the minified file actually. I checked these links